# Magento REST API details or swagger doc

Tags: java, json, magento

How to find the correct json schema to post to the magento endpoint and create an account?

Am able to create account only from the front end, I need to be able to do from the backend using curl or Postman.

http://{ipaddress}/index.php/customer/account/create/

This is an external api , i need to consume.

I want to post to this end point from java, however am not able to find the correct request schema of the json endpoint.

Any help to find the swagger end point or schema would be great

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about magento 1? Have you tried the REST API by chance? It's well written out on how you should make a call to it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html).

If you need more functionality than just creating an account, you can also take a look at the [SOAP](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.html) API which handles more things, but does not support JSON from the box. They did implement the [WS-I](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/wsi_compliance.html) complaint mode to support Java calls, so maybe that's something you'd be interested in as well.

Good luck!